# Triggering SOAP requests in a Maven Mojo

Tags: maven-2, soap, wsdl, maven-plugin, mojo

I have a WSDL which I need to trigger some commands from. I need to do this as part of a Maven Plugin (Mojo)

I'm a relative newbie to SOAP so what I want to know is this:

1) Is this possible? Can the SOAP calls be run from a Maven Plugin or does it require a container or something else?

2) If so, what tools should I use to do this? I've read about Apache Axis and have seen that it's capable of building a lot of things from the WSDL itself. Is this the sort of tool I should use? Do Mojos have a built in SOAP executor?

3) If not, what are my alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible? Can the SOAP calls be run from a Maven Plugin or does it require a container or something else?

Yes, that's possible, you do not require any kind of container to run a SOAP client.

> If so, what tools should I use to do this? I've read about Apache Axis and have seen that it's capable of building a lot of things from the WSDL itself. Is this the sort of tool I should use? Do Mojos have a built in SOAP executor?

I would consider using a JAX-WS stack like JAX-WS RI which is **included** in Java 6. Much easier and much more elegant. Here are some tutorials to get started:

- [Introducing JAX-WS 2.0 With the Java SE 6 Platform, Part 1](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/)
- [Creating a Simple Web Service and Client with JAX-WS](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html)
- [Getting Started with JAX-WS Web Services](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html)
- [Developing JAX-WS Web Service Clients](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html)

In short, use `wsimport` to generate and compile the web service artifacts needed to connect to the service and use them from the Mojo.

Comment: Hmmm... I can't always assume I'll be running on Java 6. Some projects that this Maven piece will be running through will be running on Java 5. Is that going to be a huge problem for JAX-WS?

Comment: @Drew You can provide the JAX-WS implementation (either JAX-WS RI or Apache CXF).